# RestSharp v107 not returning data

Tags: c#, restsharp

I’ve used RestSharp 106 in the past but now I’m trying to get a new project up and running with v107. I did a simple test below but I can’t get it to return any data so I must be missing something that I’m not understanding. I’ve put a breakpoint at the top of the method and can follow it all the way down until it makes the async call and then the app just quits. I see the initial logging but again nothing after the async call. I would have thought I would see some logging about the list count or even the “Application END” piece. Anyone have any ideas on what I’m doing wrong? I’ve kept but commented out some of the different things I’ve tried.

Link to the documentation I’m looking at.
https://restsharp.dev/intro.html#introduction

```
public async void Run()
        {
            _log.LogInformation("Application START");

            try
            {
                var listPPC = new List<PriorPeriodCorrection>();

                listPPC = await CallApi();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.LogError("Error: {0} | {1} | {2}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException);
            }

            _log.LogInformation("Application END");
        }


        public async Task<List<PriorPeriodCorrection>> CallApi()
        {
            var listPPC = new List<PriorPeriodCorrection>();

            var apiURL = "https://example.com";
            var apiEndpoint = "api/payroll/getpriorpaycorrectiondata/from/2021-12-01/to/2021-12-07";
            var proxyAddress = "http://example.com:9400";


            var apiUsername = "someusername";
            var apiPassword = "4PsaI69@tuv";


            var options = new RestClientOptions(apiURL)
            {
                ThrowOnAnyError = true,
                Timeout = 1000,
                Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyAddress)
            };

            var client = new RestClient(options);
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(apiUsername, apiPassword);


            var request = new RestRequest(apiEndpoint);

            try
            {
                listPPC = await client.GetAsync<List<PriorPeriodCorrection>>(request);

                //var response = await client.GetAsync<PriorPeriodCorrection>(request);
                //var response = await client.GetAsync<List<PriorPeriodCorrection>>(request);
                //var response = await client.GetAsync(request);

                //if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.Content))
                //{
                //    listPPC = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PriorPeriodCorrection>>(response.Content);
                //}
                //else
                //    _log.LogInformation("Response Content is Blank or NULL.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.LogError("Error: {0} | {1} | {2}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException);
            }

            _log.LogInformation("Response count: {0}", listPPC.Count);

            return listPPC;
        }
```

Comment: What .NET version you are using, and which OS? It seems to be platform-specific, and I would suspect the proxy thing.

Comment: I'm using .Net Core 5 on a Windows 10 computer.